# Using repeated information columns in MySQL database to avoid making extra queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the current setup:

My `tests` table:

`user_id:` is the user that submitted the test

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tests` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
);
```

---

My `attempts` table:

`user_id:` is the user that started the test

`last_answered_question:` is the index of the last question the user answered

`finished:` if the user finished the test (this column only exists to make things easier)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attempts` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `test_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `last_answered_question` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `finished` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
);
```

---

My `users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL
);
```

---

My `questions` table:

`user_id:` is the user that submitted the question

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `information` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
);
```

---

And my `tests` and `questions` pivot table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question_test` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `test_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
);
```

---

Let me explain some stuff:

A `test` is basically a collection of `questions`.

A `question` may belong to many `tests`.

`Tests` and `questions` may have different owners/submitters.

The `attempts` table tracks `tests` that a `user` is currently doing. A `user` can only start a new `attempt` if there are no unfinished `attempts` for the same `test`.

I didn't include keys to make everything a bit cleaner (They're correct set on my actually database schema)

**EDIT:**

The `information` column in the `questions` table is just JSON information: the question itself, the possible answers, and the correct answer index/number.

the `chosen_answer` in the `answers` table, is an index/number of the answer that the `user` chose as correct while attempting to complete a `test`.

I chose to use JSON because I didn't really see the need to add another table just for possible answers in a question.

The `information` column looks something like this:

```
{
    "question": "What's the first letter of the alphabet?",
    "possibleAnswers": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    ],
    "correctAnswer": "0"
}
```

---

The problem I'm having is designing the `answers` table. The first Schema I thought was something like this:

`chosen_answer:` is the user's answer for the question (I'm not really sure how I'm going to implement this)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `chosen_answer` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `attempt_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
);
```

I'm considering whether or not I should add `question_id` and `user_id` columns, since I can find out the IDs by querying the `attempts` table.

The good thing is: it'll be easier to find all `answers` for a single `question` and generate some statistics. It'll be also easier to find all `answers` for a single `user` and generate more stats.

The bad thing: while reading about relational databases, I saw somewhere that you shouldn't repeat information in your tables, because that's the purpose of database relations)

I'm currently using Laravel5 to implement this entire system, and I'm very new to PHP and Laravel5.

I'm trying to always use Eloquent ORM to work with my database because it makes updating entries alot easier

---

Things going through my mind thinking about this 'problem':

In order to find out the % of correct `answers` for a `user`, I'll have to query every `attempt` and then query `answers` from those `attempts` and then query the `questions` table to figure out the correct answer.

Is there a correct/efficient way to tackle this problem avoiding multiple/big queries/complex queries? (I hope I made everything as clear as possible, I really want to avoid implementing something 'bad' and have to redo everything)

---

**EDIT**: The main thing I'm trying to tackle here

I want to use Eloquent ORM as much as possible (it allows me to define custom functions and it feels more like OOP, which I'm more used to)

I can use the Query Builder and completely avoid the need for `user_id` and `question_id` in my database because I can just join tables using `attempt_id` but I'll not be using Eloquent (which is not a big problem but this is not what I want).

I can still use Eloquent ORM but it seems alot more inefficient. I'm thinking about this situation:

I wanna know how many correct answers a `user` has:

If I have the `user_id` column, this is an easy query, just need to select every `answer` that has `user_id = x`.

If I don't have the `user_id`, I need to query every `attempt` the user made, and then query the `answers` related to every `attempt`. (Here's the 'problem', is there a way to efficiently solve this situation using Eloquent ORM besides adding those columns to my schema?)

Comment: First thing I notice is no `FOREIGN KEY` clauses in your table creation. Additionally you'll want to define indices on your columns that will be queried. If you set up your index and foreign key structure properly a join shouldn't cause problems and you're probably fine omitting things from the `answers` column.

Comment: @miken32 I actually forgot to include the keys in the questions description (they're correct setup in my database schema). I exported using phpmyadmin, so the code that adds the keys is actually at the bottom of the file (hope it made sense).

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm not really sure if I understand what you're trying to say but the only reason I'm adding `user_id` and `question_id` columns is to make my queries simpler (since they are never going to change) since I can find them using just the `attempt_id` but in order to do that I need to execute another query or make a more complex one (which is not a problem).

Comment: It isn't about designing queries to find things. It is a about relationships. i.e. Which entities directly connect to each other. IMO, Specifically, what is an `Answer`? It is the `value` provided to a particular `Question` on this `Attempt` at completing the `Test`? i.e. it belongs to `attempts` and needs to know which `question` it is for.

Comment: Database design is like everything else that we do... there is no `one true model` for the real world situation. Your  database model seems perfectly ok to me.

Comment: @RyanVincent I actually forgot to include some crucial information in my question (I got really frustrated thinking about what I thought was a problem)... You're correct, an `answer` is exactly that (I forgot to add the `value` or `chosen_answer` column). The problem I created is trying to use Eloquent ORM (I can easily create the query needed for this problem) but I really want to be a able to use custom functions (something that Eloquent allows me). But on second thought I don't really think I should be using Eloquent at all. I'm just curious if it's actually possible.

Comment: Which `Answer` definition are you going with - the original one or the:     Answer(_id_,  _attempt_id_,    _question_id_ , _chosen_id_)? This will work fine in any `ORM` directly as it is all `one to many` relationships.

Comment: @RyanVincent I've added some edits to the original question, I hope it helps make things clearer. I think I know how I'm going about this problem (just using Query Builder instead of Eloquent, since I don't really see custom functions being a necessity or needing to update my DB)